# Python: Get list index count for a list of strings

Tags: python

I have the following..

```
words = ["a", "see", "me"]
sentances = [
 "a dog goes into the home.",
 "I see a dog around me, I can also see the dog",
 "The dog can see me with a bone"
]
```

As an example and what I'm looking to do is get those words into just another dict or complex dict that has each time a word is found but the index count of the sentance it is in

```
{
  a: [0,1,2],
  see: [1,2,2],
  me: [2]
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: What is the logic behind this: `a: [0,1,2]`?

Comment: I think `see` should be `[1,1,2]`, right?

Comment: see [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Answer (score 2):

words = ["a", "see", "me"]
sentances = [
"a dog goes into the home.",
"I see a dog around me, I can also see the dog",
"The dog can see me with a bone"
]

```
res = {}

for i in range(len(sentances)):
    sentance = sentances[i]
    sentance = sentance.split()
    for word in sentance:
        
        if word in words:
            try:
                res[word].append(i)
            except:
                res[word] = [i]
        
print(res)
# {'a': [0, 1, 2], 'see': [1, 1, 2], 'me': [2]}
```

This works!

Answer (score 1):

You could make counter for each sentences, iterate those `Counters` and check whether it exists, so you could do it with a nested comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["a", "see", "me"]
sentances = [
    "a dog goes into the home.",
    "I see a dog around me, I can also see the dog",
    "The dog can see me with a bone"
]

sentances_counter = list(map(lambda s: Counter(s.split()), sentances))

result = {
    word: [index for index, sentence in enumerate(sentances_counter) if word in sentence for _ in range(sentence[word])]
    for word in words
}

print(result)
```

This gave me:

```
{'a': [0, 1, 2], 'see': [1, 1, 2], 'me': [2]}
```